# Getting ID from get_posts within a loop in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

My first question here, so please feel free to direct me elsewhere (yes, I did try searching for duplicates, but my stackoverflow skills may be limited).

I'm building a Wordpress plugin that creates a front-end dashboard to edit a custom post type. I'm using a get_posts query to display a list of the current user's posts, and their respective edit forms.

The problem is that I cannot seem to access the post ID from the WP_Post Object. When I var-dump everything seems kosher....

Here is my code (simplified) :
    $currentuser = get_current_user_id( );
        $args = array(
            'author' => $currentuser,
            'posts_per_page'   => -1,
            'post_type' => 'board_post', 
            );

```
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $jb_post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
?>
<a href="#edit_<?=$jb_post->id ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_<?=$jb_post->id ?>" class="list-group-item"> Edit </a> <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Nothing is outputted where the post ID ought to be.

```
<?=get_the_title($jb_post); ?>
```

That outputs the correct title.
When I tried all of the following, it echoes the ID of the parent page :

```
<?=get_the_ID($jb_post); ?>
<?=the_ID($jb_post); ?>
<?=get_the_ID(); ?>
<?=the_ID(); ?>
```

I presume that there is some sort of structural problem with the way I'm pulling up these posts. Throwing wp_reset_query doesn't adress the problem. Does anyone know of any resources regarding best practices for this sort of thing?

EDIT: Here is the var_dump($jb_post)

```
array(15) {
[0]=>
  object(WP_Post)#285 (24) {
    ["ID"]=>
    int(253)
    ["post_author"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["post_date"]=>
    string(19) "2014-04-17 18:36:27"
    ["post_date_gmt"]=>
    string(19) "2014-04-17 18:36:27"
    ["post_content"]=>
    string(8) "gsdljdkf"
    ["post_title"]=>
    string(10) "Shortcoded"
    ["post_excerpt"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_status"]=>
    string(7) "publish"
    ["comment_status"]=>
    string(6) "closed"
    ["ping_status"]=>
    string(4) "open"
    ["post_password"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_name"]=>
    string(12) "shortcoded-2"
    ["to_ping"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["pinged"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_modified"]=>
    string(19) "2014-04-17 18:36:27"
    ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
    string(19) "2014-04-17 18:36:27"
    ["post_content_filtered"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["post_parent"]=>
    int(0)
    ["guid"]=>
    string(51) "http://XXX.0.0.1:4001/wordpress/board/shortcoded-2/"
    ["menu_order"]=>
    int(0)
    ["post_type"]=>
    string(10) "board_post"
    ["post_mime_type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["comment_count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(WP_Post)#284 (24) {
(so on and so forth for all posts)
}
```

Comment: show us `var_dump($myposts)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of the reason that you are not specifying the $args array parameters. Once, you specify them, you would get the desired results.

Also, your code: get_the_title($jb_post); needs to be like this: get_the_title($jb_post->ID);

For get_posts() complete reference , go to: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.

The title is working with both  get_the_title($jb_post); and get_the_title($jb_post->ID);  and the arguments were defined. 
All of the other fields output from the correct object, except for get_the_ID() get_the_ID($jb_post->id), etc.

Comment: It is because both these functions work only in Wordpress' The Loop ([link](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)) and you have not used it. Also, you don't need get_the_ID($jb_post->id), you can just use $jb_post->ID, but remember to keep ID in capital.

Comment: Andd it was an uncapitalised ID.
What an obvious oversight, sorry and thank you so much for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
if ( $images = get_posts(array(
       'post_parent' => $post->ID,
       'post_type' => $post_type,
       'numberposts' => -1,
       'orderby'        => 'title',
       'category_name' => 'category',
       'order'           => 'ASC',
       'post_mime_type' => 'image',
   ))) :
   ?>

   
   <div class="" >
       
   <?php 
       foreach( $images as $image ) {
           $attachmenturl_meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $image->ID );
           $attachmenturl = wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID);
           $attachmentimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->ID, 'full' );
           $imageDescription = apply_filters( 'the_description' , $image->post_content );
           $imageTitle = apply_filters( 'the_title' , $image->post_title );
          
           $i++;
           if (!empty($imageTitle)){
               ?>
  <!-- Here show image -->
           <img src=<?php echo $attachmentimage[0] ?> />
<!--  this container show title -->
           <?php echo $imageTitle; ?> 

    /><span class='text-center'> <?php echo $imageTitle; ?></span>
```